# Why Firebase's authentication fires twice in this sample?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using Firebase's `auth().createUserWithEmailAndpassword` to create a user, I was thinking if the email and password already exist, only the `catch(function())` will be called, otherwise `then(function(user))` will be called. But in the testing, both got called, is it the expected behavior? Thanks.

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword("test@test.com", "passwrd" ).catch(function (error) {
    if (error) {
        if (error.code === "auth/email-already-in-use") {
            console.log('already exists')
        }
    }
}).then(function (user) {
    console.log('user created', user)
    if (user) {
        db.ref('users/' + user.uid).set(self.info)
    }
})
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That occurs because you've placed the `catch` *before* the `then`.

The `catch` catches the error and then passes control to the subsequent `then` - the `user` will be `undefined` as that's what's returned by the `catch`.

The usual way of structuring the control flow is to put the `catch` last.

```js
firebase
  .auth()
  .createUserWithEmailAndPassword("test@test.com", "passwrd" )
  .then(function (user) {
    console.log('user created', user)
    if (user) {
      db.ref('users/' + user.uid).set(self.info)
    }
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    if (error) {
      if (error.code === "auth/email-already-in-use") {
        console.log('already exists')
      }
    }
  });
```

There is more information on Promises and their control flow [here](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/promises).

Comment: Thanks, it works! usually I put then first before catch,  never thought it will have impact on that, so does this also happen to Promise in general?

Comment: Yep, it's general. The point of it is that you can `catch` an error and then return something appropriate to a subsequent `then`.